# .click() not working in iPad only, inside of backbone.js app

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm having a very strange and frusturating issue -- I have written a .click() event in a view of my backbone.js app (first time writing one), and it sucessfully fires in every desktop browser, but it will not work on the iPad.

The code is like this:

```
if (something) {
 $('a.link').click();
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

I have no idea why it's happening. I am using backbone.js, with backbone.touch.js if that means anything. I've been banging my head against the wall for hours on this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you confirm this code line is runned? (via console.log for example)

Comment: not familiar with backbone.touch.js, but does it translate the click into a touch event for you?

Comment: @SimonBoudrias I can confirmed that it ran, I've alerted before and after and it seems to plow through it

Comment: @kinakuta backbone.touch.js merges click and touch events but (to my knowledge) only for the events you declare in the 'events' object, so this one shouldn't be affected, I thought. Here's the link https://github.com/nervetattoo/backbone.touch

Comment: do you have a click handler that should be firing then when that click event is triggered?

Comment: The code is a bunch of links in a navigation, and I want to trigger a click on a navigation item if a condition is met. It's strange to me that it works on the desktop perfectly but not the iPad

Comment: I don't have an iPad, so I'm only speculating, but maybe you can't fire click events that way - how about using custom events and handling them in the same way you'd handle the click events on the navigation items? Backbone has a pretty good built-in way for you to do that.

Comment: @kinakuta I'm not aware of how to do that.. would you be able to provide an example? The click events in other areas of the application seem to work, but if this is the case, I was trying to avoid using another external library if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using custom events instead of simulating a click:

To fire a custom event in a backbone object, just trigger it. For example, in your model:

```
this.trigger('click:navitem');
```

Then, where you're listenting for these events, for example in the view attached to that model:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'click:navitem', doFunc);
```

where doFunc is the name of your handler.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYpvx/5/) demo. The example is contrived, so it may not match the structure of your application, but the point is to demonstrate firing and listening for custom events. In this example I just did everything in the same view, but the origin of where the events fire can be a model or a collection, as long as where you're listening for those events can reference the originator of the events. It's essentially backbone's implementation of pub/sub which, of course, could be implemented outside of backbone with jquery, pubsub, or various other libraries, but you get this from backbone for free.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for making it a fiddle. There's not a major rush (I will not be able to test it right away), but if it works I will definitely accept your answer right away! Thank you for your help!